# Multilange support - need some help in xkeyval

Tags: key-value, xkeyval

I'm trying to do some improvements in the multiaudience package. In particular, I would like to have one latex document containing multiple languages.

For simplification reasons the texts of the multiple languages should be arranged paragraphwise. In fact most of these things can be done with the multiaudience package already.

Now I'm facing the problem that for the document releasing it might be much simpler not create two pdf documents per language, but one common. Especially the \section commands are problematic here - as the title of the first and second language should not create two "real" sections.

Let me give an easy to understand code fragment:

```
\showto{E}{\section{english section}
\showto{D}{\section{german section}

\showto{E}{english text}
\showto{D}{german text}
```

this will work fine, if I'm choosing `\DefCurrentAudience{D}` or `\DefCurrentAudience{E}`, but it will create a mess when using `\DefCurrentAudience{D,E}`. The text will appear in the wrong section.

I would like to get an output of that kind:

```
1. english section / german section
[E] english text
[D] german text
```

My idea was to write a new (multi-language)section command, that combines the two headlines in one, in case of multiple activated languages

```
\mlsection{E=english section title, G=german section title}
```

Please give me a hint how to separate the key and value pairs. Any other idea is of course welcome, too

Thanks
Georg

here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multilanguage}

\SetNewLanguage{D}
\SetNewLanguage{E}
\DefCurrentLanguage{D,E}


\begin{document}

\section{Erstens}
\showto{D}{THIS IS GERMAN}

\showto{E}{THIS IS ENGLISH}

\showto{D}{\section{GERMAN SECTION}}
\showto{E}{\section{ENGLISH SECTION}}

new try

\mlsection{G=German Section, E=English Section}

\end{document}
```

and the new package "multilanguage" - a simplified version of multiaudience

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{multilanguage}
[2023/09/08 v1.0 Some tests]

\providecommand*\CurrentLanguage{default}

\def\DefCurrentLanguage#1{\def\CurrentLanguage{#1}}

\newif\if@MULTLANG@shown
\@MULTLANG@showntrue

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\def\SetNewLanguage#1{
    \define@key{MULTLANG}{#1}[]{
        \def\@MULTLANG@currkey{#1}
        \@for\@tempa:=\CurrentLanguage \do{%
            \ifx\@MULTLANG@currkey\@tempa
                \@MULTLANG@showntrue
            \fi
        }%
    }%
}

\long\def\showto#1#2{%
    \@MULTLANG@shownfalse
    \setkeys{MULTLANG}{#1}
    \if@MULTLANG@shown#2\fi
}
  

  
\long\def\mlsection#1{%
    \@for\@tempa:=#1\do {%
        % SOME CODE IS MISSING HERE
    }%
  }
```

@Skillmon
I really like your little macro shown below. I went through the code - I guess I'm understand what you are doing. A also found a nice way to use the code for writing one content-file first in german and then the same content file in english. Furthermore, -especially for corrections- I'm using a stacked version, where german and english is published paragraph by paragraph. I'm searching for a nice for highlight the independet languages. E.g. English is green, german in red, or Text-ideicator before the actual text-block. Is there an easy solution?
thx georg

Comment: Can you please create a complete minimal example. Currently we can only guess where `\DefCurrentAudience` and `\showto` might come from. A small example starting at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` that only contains the necessary packages/code for your `\DefCurrentAudience` and `\showto` and one sectioning command should do.

Comment: done - please see above

Comment: Your definitions contain many unwanted spaces. You should add `%` after `{` at the end of line, for instance. Same is true for `}` inside a macro definition.

Comment: Also, inside your `\SetNewLanguage` you want `\ifx`, not `\if` to compare `\@MULTLANG@currkey` to `\@tempa`.

Comment: why \ifx? and else case is not needed?

Comment: Because with `\if` you're expanding `\@MULTLANG@currkey` and if it is defined to be two equal characters at the start you're not doing what you expect it to do. Try using `\showto{aahaha}{This is sneaky}` with your current definition.

Comment: I updated the code, based on your remarks - thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how flexible you are in your interface, but I'd propose the following code. Instead of checking which languages are active on every usage it activates only the used languages on `\DefCurrentLanguage`, and then uses internal macros to track this state (so it doesn't pick up extern changes to `\CurrentLanguage`). The advantage is that this way we can fast and expandably check whether a language is active.

For the key/value part of `\mlsection` the following uses `expkv` because it is fully expandable. This way we can add keys like `label` to set a `\label`, or `default` that gets used if no other language was used before it.

I also changed the way new languages are defined to accept a comma separated list of languages, instead of using multiple calls. For the csv-processing the following uses `\ekvcsvloop` instead of LaTeX's built-in `\@for`, because I think it has a cleaner interface (it also handles space stripping correctly).

If you don't want to use `expkv`, the following could in principle be coded using `expl3` as well (but since I'm the author of `expkv` the following uses it).

```
\begin{filecontents}{multilanguage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{multilanguage}
[2023/09/08 v1.0 Some tests]

\RequirePackage{expkv}

\providecommand*\CurrentLanguage{}

\protected\def\DefCurrentLanguage
  {%
    \@MULTLANG@deactivate
    \ekvcsvloop\@MULTLANG@activate
  }
\protected\def\@MULTLANG@activate#1%
  {%
    \expandafter\let
      \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
      \@firstoftwo
  }

\newcommand\@MULTLANG@deactivate{}

\protected\def\SetNewLanguages{\ekvcsvloop\@MULTLANG@new@language}
\protected\def\@MULTLANG@new@language#1%
  {%
    \@ifundefined{@MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}}%
      {%
        % add it to the list of languages which need to be deactivated on
        % language change
        \edef\@MULTLANG@deactivate
          {%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\@MULTLANG@deactivate}%
            \unexpanded\expandafter
              {%
                \expandafter\let
                  \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
                  \@secondoftwo
              }%
          }%
        % init the language
        \expandafter\let
          \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
          \@secondoftwo
      }%
      {%
        \PackageError{multilanguage}%
          {Language `\detokenize{#1}' already defined.}{}%
      }%
  }

\def\showto#1%
  {%
    \@ifundefined{@MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}}%
      {%
        % expandable error message
        \ekverr{multilanguage}{Unknown language `#1'}%
        \@gobble
      }%
      {%
        \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
          \@firstofone
          \@gobble
      }%
  }

\ekvsetdef\@MULTLANG@section@keys{MULTLANG/section}
% keep in mind that the key will be used in an expanded-context, so we use
% \unexpanded
\ekvdef{MULTLANG/section}{label}{\unexpanded{\label{#1}}}
% default will only be used if no other language was used before it
\ekvdef{MULTLANG/section}{default}
  {%
    \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }
% every unknown key will be interpreted as a language key
\ekvdefunknown{MULTLANG/section}
  {%
    \showto{#2}
      {%
        \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
          \space/\space
        \else
          \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
        \fi
        \unexpanded{#1}%
      }%
  }

\def\mlsection#1%
  {%
    % group to keep the notfirst-flag local
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\section\expanded
        {{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
  }
\def\@MULTLANG@missing@value#1%
  {%
    \ekvifdefinedNoVal{#1}{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{#1}}%
      {\ekverr{multilanguage}{Missing value for `#1'}}%
  }
\def\@MULTLANG@mlsection#1#2%
  {%
    \ekvifdefined{MULTLANG/section}{#1}{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{{#1}={#2}}}%
    \showto{#1}
      {%
        \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
          \space/\space
        \else
          \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
        \fi
        \unexpanded{#2}%
      }%
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multilanguage}

\SetNewLanguages{D,E}
\DefCurrentLanguage{D,E}


\begin{document}

\section{Erstens}
\showto{D}{THIS IS GERMAN}

\showto{E}{THIS IS ENGLISH}

\showto{D}{\section{GERMAN SECTION}}
\showto{E}{\section{ENGLISH SECTION}}

new try

\mlsection{D=German Section, E=English Section, default=FALLBACK TITLE, label=sec:multilang}

See section~\ref{sec:multilang}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW - I'm really impressed!
I just compiled our code and it's exactly what I needed. I have 15 year experiecene with latex, but I never digged that much into the package-codes - therefore I still needs some time to understand what you did here - GREAT!

Last question: Do you think it is a good idea to combine multiaudience and your "multilanguage"-code? In fact I will need in the end not only english and german, but an english version for an internal audience and an external audience (and the same for the german language). There difference is that some text should be hidden (or replaced)

Comment: @Georg I don't have any real experience with `multiaudience` and never looked at its code, so can't give a definitive answer on this (maybe I find the time this evening, but no guarantee). I think the two should work in parallel, if you need an interface between the two the code in my answer would need to be altered (or entirely rewritten, depends on the package code).