# Multilanguage Code and for loops

Tags: xkeyval

I'm really happy with a piece of code that was provided by @Skillmon, please see here

[Multilange support - need some help in xkeyval](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695478/multilange-support-need-some-help-in-xkeyval)

For working on a document it is usefull to create the different languages close to each other section by section. Nevertheless, the final document needs all sections in the first language and then all sections in the second language and so on. Of course the sections counters need to be resetted, too.

I tried to realize this with a simple for-loop, but I didn't manage

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multilanguage}
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\SetNewAudience{intern}
\SetNewAudience{extern}
\DefCurrentAudience{intern,extern}

\SetNewLanguages{DE,EN}

\begin{document}
\foreach \langlooper in {DE,EN}{
\newpage
\DefCurrentLanguage{\langlooper}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Erstens}
\lang{DE}{THIS IS GERMAN\\
\showto{intern} {DE: INTERN TEXT}\\
\showto{extern}{DE: EXTERN TEXT}\\
}
\lang{EN}{THIS IS ENGLISH\\
\showto{intern} {EN: INTERN TEXT}\\
\showto{extern}{EN: EXTERN TEXT}\\
}

\lang{DE}{\section{GERMAN SECTION}}
\lang{EN}{\section{ENGLISH SECTION}}


new try

\mlsection{DE=German Section, EN=English Section, default=FALLBACK TITLE, label=sec:multilang}

\begin{langen}{DE}
THIS PARAGRAPH IS GERMAN.

THIS, TOO
\end{langen}

\begin{langen}{EN}
THIS PARAGRAPH IS ENGLISH.

THIS, TOO
\end{langen}

\mlsubsection{DE=German Subsection, EN=English Subsection,}
See section~\ref{sec:multilang}.

See in figure \ref{fig:fig2}

\begin{figure}
\centering{
An EXAMPLE
}
\caption{\lang{EN}{A caption} \lang{DE}{Eine Bildunterschrift}}
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering{
An EXAMPLE
}
\mlcaption{DE=Eine Bildunterschrift, EN=A caption, label=fig:fig2}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Seems that the \langlooper key is not correctly used as argument
Any hint?

Thanks
Georg

PS: Here is the code of multilanguage.sty

```
%% LaTeX2e file `multilanguage.sty'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `test3' on 2023/09/11.
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{multilanguage}
[2023/09/08 v1.0 Some tests]

\RequirePackage{expkv}

\providecommand*\CurrentLanguage{}

\protected\def\DefCurrentLanguage
  {%
    \@MULTLANG@deactivate
    \ekvcsvloop\@MULTLANG@activate
  }
\protected\def\@MULTLANG@activate#1%
  {%
    \expandafter\let
      \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
      \@firstoftwo
  }

\newcommand\@MULTLANG@deactivate{}

\protected\def\SetNewLanguages{\ekvcsvloop\@MULTLANG@new@language}
\protected\def\@MULTLANG@new@language#1%
  {%
    \@ifundefined{@MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}}%
      {%
        % add it to the list of languages which need to be deactivated on
        % language change
        \edef\@MULTLANG@deactivate
          {%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\@MULTLANG@deactivate}%
            \unexpanded\expandafter
              {%
                \expandafter\let
                  \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
                  \@secondoftwo
              }%
          }%
        % init the language
        \expandafter\let
          \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
          \@secondoftwo
      }%
      {%
        \PackageError{multilanguage}%
          {Language `\detokenize{#1}' already defined.}{}%
      }%
  }

\def\lang#1%
  {%
    \@ifundefined{@MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}}%
      {%
        % expandable error message
        \ekverr{multilanguage}{Unknown language `#1'}%
        \@gobble
      }%
      {%
        \csname @MULTLANG@@iflang@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
          \@firstofone
          \@gobble
      }%
  }
  
\RequirePackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{langen}[1]{%
 \lang{#1}{\BODY}} 

\ekvsetdef\@MULTLANG@section@keys{MULTLANG/section}
% keep in mind that the key will be used in an expanded-context, so we use
% \unexpanded
\ekvdef{MULTLANG/section}{label}{\unexpanded{\label{#1}}}
% default will only be used if no other language was used before it
\ekvdef{MULTLANG/section}{default}
  {%
    \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }
% every unknown key will be interpreted as a language key
\ekvdefunknown{MULTLANG/section}
  {%
    \lang{#2}
      {%
        \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
          \space/\space
        \else
          \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
        \fi
        \unexpanded{#1}%
      }%
  }

\def\mlsection#1%
  {%
    % group to keep the notfirst-flag local
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\section\expanded
        {{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
  }
 \def\mlsubsection#1%
  {%
    % group to keep the notfirst-flag local
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\subsection\expanded
        {{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
  }
\def\mlsubsubsection#1%
  {%
    % group to keep the notfirst-flag local
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\subsubsection\expanded
        {{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
  }
\def\@MULTLANG@missing@value#1%
  {%
    \ekvifdefinedNoVal{#1}{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{#1}}%
      {\ekverr{multilanguage}{Missing value for `#1'}}%
  }
\def\@MULTLANG@mlsection#1#2%
  {%
    \ekvifdefined{MULTLANG/section}{#1}{\@MULTLANG@section@keys{{#1}={#2}}}%
    \lang{#1}
      {%
        \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
          \space/\space
        \else
          \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
        \fi
        \unexpanded{#2}%
      }%
  }
  
  
\ekvsetdef\@MULTLANG@caption@keys{MULTLANG/section}
% keep in mind that the key will be used in an expanded-context, so we use
% \unexpanded
\ekvdef{MULTLANG/section}{label}{\unexpanded{\label{#1}}}
% default will only be used if no other language was used before it
\ekvdef{MULTLANG/section}{default}
  {%
    \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }
% every unknown key will be interpreted as a language key
\ekvdefunknown{MULTLANG/caption}
  {%
    \lang{#2}
      {%
        \ifcsname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
          \space/\space
        \else
          \expandafter\@gobble\csname @MULTLANG@@flag@notfirst\endcsname
        \fi
        \unexpanded{#1}%
      }%
  }  
  
\def\mlcaption#1%
  {%
    % group to keep the notfirst-flag local
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\caption\expanded
        {{\@MULTLANG@caption@keys{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
  }
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile as \lang is not defined.

Comment: Please use the multilanguage-file from the before mentioned topic

Comment: I did and it doesn't define \lang.

Comment: I added the code to the question above... sorry, my fault